# How to display a 2D shape over OpenGL with Python and PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I am trying to make a game with python, pygame and OpenGL and I want to make a crosshair in the center of the screen so when they look around they can see what they are going to click. I made it so it hides their cursor and moves it to the center of the window but I do not know how to make a shape go on top of opengl in pygame. I am a beginner to pygame and to opengl. It is probably really easy but I could not find an answer to it where I looked. 
 Please help out how you can and thanks in advance.

Here is my code if you want to make sure what you do works in my situation.

```
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

block = [
    [0,1,0],
    [1,0,0],
    [1,0,1],
    [0,0,1],
    [1,1,0],
    [0,1,1]
]


def Cube(x,y,z):
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    glColor3f(block[0][0], block[0][1], block[0][2])  # N
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glColor3f(block[1][0], block[1][1], block[1][2])  # S
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[2][0], block[2][1], block[2][2])  # W
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[3][0], block[3][1], block[3][2])  # E
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y,     z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glColor3f(block[4][0], block[4][1], block[4][2])  # U
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y + 1, z - .5)
    glColor3f(block[5][0], block[5][1], block[5][2])  # D
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z + .5)
    glVertex3f(x - .5, y, z - .5)
    glVertex3f(x + .5, y, z - .5)
    glEnd()
def main():
    controls = False
    pygame.init()

    display = (800,600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glClearDepth(1.0)

    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
    glCullFace(GL_BACK)
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
    glDepthRange(0.0,1.0)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 100.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
    while True:
        if controls:
            pygame.mouse.set_pos([400, 300])
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
        else:
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    controls = not controls
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1,)
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube(0,0,0)
        Cube(0,1,0)
        Cube(1,1,1)
        glCullFace(GL_BACK)
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(.01)    


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that drawing by [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences and the fixed function matrix stack is deprecated since decades.

---

Anyway, I recommend to draw [head-up display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display) elements using orthographic projection.

Create a function which draws the cross hair in window coordinates:

```py
def Crosshair(x, y, w):
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glVertex2f(x-w, y)
    glVertex2f(x+w, y)
    glVertex2f(x, y-w)
    glVertex2f(x, y+w)
    glEnd()
```

Apply the projection matrix to the projection matrix stack and the model matrix to the model view matrix stack. See [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml):

```py
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 100.0)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
```

Since the cross hair always should be on top of the view, you have to disable the [depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test).

```py
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

mX, mY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
Crosshair(mX, 600-mY, 20)

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

Likely you can change the depth function ([`glDepthFunc`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthFunc.xhtml)) to `GL_ALWAYS` and change the [`glDepthMask`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthMask.xhtml)

Use [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) to lad the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) and use [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) to set up an orthographic projection 1:1 to window coordinates;

```py
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0.0, display[0], 0.0, display[1], -1.0, 1.0)
```

Use [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) to store and restore the matrixes on the matrix stack:

```py
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 100.0)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
while True:
    if controls:
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([400, 300])
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    else:
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                controls = not controls
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    glClearDepth(1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glRotate(1, 3, 1, 1,)
    Cube(0,0,0)
    Cube(0,1,0)
    Cube(1,1,1)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glPushMatrix()
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0.0, display[0], 0.0, display[1], -1.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glPushMatrix()
    glLoadIdentity()

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    mX, mY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    Crosshair(mX, 600-mY, 20)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glPopMatrix()
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glPopMatrix()

    glCullFace(GL_BACK)
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(.01)
```